# Permutations and generators and matrix representations.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, representation-theory

I am considering all possible permutations of 3 elements and I want to construct these using the generating elements (switch 1 and 3) and (switch 1 and 2). We can represent these using the matrices:

$${\bf P}_{13} = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0&0&1\\
0&1&0\\
1&0&0
\end{array}\right] \hspace{1cm} {\bf P}_{12} = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&0\\
1&0&0\\
0&0&1
\end{array}\right]
$$

We see that ${({\bf P}_{12})}^2 = {({\bf P}_{13})}^2 = {\bf I}$, so higher exponents than 1 are of no use to build.
Instead we alternate which element to multiply with:
$${\bf P}(n) = \prod_{i=1}^n {{\bf P}_{12}}^{mod(i,2)}{{\bf P}_{13}}^{mod(i+1,2)}$$

This seems to build all 6 possible permutations for me. Is it a coincidence that just happens to work for my relatively small group or can this approach be made systematic for larger groups?

Comment: Well every permutation can be written as the product of transpositions. Is this the result you are looking for?

Comment: Not if, but how.